# Reloaded Jquery UI datepicker doesn't work in inline mode

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I loaded UI datepicker in inline mode.So,I make tow buttons to load and remove it.But when I reload it again.The datepicker showed but can't select any day or change month, and firebug reported error.

just simple code:
js:

```
var panelContents1 = $('<div />',{'id':'igto1_WH'}).append($('<div />',{'id':'igto1_whDatePicker'}).datepicker());

$('#load').click(function(){ $('#loadDiv').html(panelContents1); }) 
$('#empty').click(function(){ $('#loadDiv').empty(); })
```

and html:

```
<p id="load"> load </p>
<p id="empty"> empty </p>
<div id="loadDiv"></div>
```

Thank you very much!!

My own solution:

```
 $('#load').click(function(){
    $('#loadDiv').html(panelContents1).find('#igto1_whDatePicker').datepicker();

        })

 $('#empty').click(function(){
          $('#igto1_whDatePicker').datepicker('destroy');
    $('#loadDiv').empty();
         })

 var panelContents1 = $('<div />',{'id':'igto1_WH'}).append($('<div />',{'id':'igto1_whDatePicker'}));
```

Comment: do you need multiple datepickers or is always just one visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens in your demo is because you're creating the variable `panelContents1` and appending it into the DOM, then the `$('#loadDiv').empty();` call is destroying vital elements that the datepicker needs.  Later you're appending that **same** variable (set of elements), that's the root of all your issues here.

As a fix, creating the datepicker inside the `click` handler would create a new one each time and not have this issue with appending a now-broken one, like this:

```
$('#load').click(function(){ 
    var panelContents1 = $('<div />',{'id':'igto1_WH'}).append($('<div />',{'id':'igto1_whDatePicker'}).datepicker());
    $('#loadDiv').html(panelContents1); 
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6KSqN/).  Basically just create a new element when appending, not one that's affected by previous DOM interactions like your demo.  For those doing a double-take at the code above, [`.html(jQueryObject)` is a shortcut for `.empty().append(jQueryObject)`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/manipulation.js#L262).